Calling abstract method within abstract class
After upgrading from Angular 7 to 10, my code started triggering the error

TypeError: this.formatValue is not a function

Here's the code in question, there's an abstract class in which a non-abstract method is calling an abstract method.
The code compiles and it's only when opening the page that nothing loads and I get this error in the browser JS console.
export abstract class InputValue<T = any> extends InputAbstract {
...
    getValue(): T | null {
        return this.formatValue(this.rawValue);
    }
...
    /**
     * Tries to convert a value of any type to a value of type T or null if failed
     * @param value
     * @return {T | null}
     */
    abstract formatValue(value: any): T | null;

It's also later used in other abstract classes that extend this InputValue abstract class:
formatValue(value: any): string | null {
    return [null, void 0, ''].includes(value) ? null : String(value);
}

UPDATE
here's the Stackblitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-apacqk


please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue happening

will do. thank you for your comment

I've added the project to Stackblitz, however, I'm unable to start the application at all with the error error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error
